# What is a best practice way to use typo3 user permissions in v10 and higher?

Tags: permissions, typo3

In older versions of Typo3 it was possible to assign multiple user groups in the "Access"-view of typo3 to specific items of the page tree, nowadays you can only assign one group, which leads to a lot of problems, when not wanting to assign a different group for every item of the page tree. Especially when multiple groups are supposed to share access to specific sites, but also include other sites which are not in both groups. Even trying to make a page viewable by one group AND viewable/editable by another, while having different other sites in both groups seems like a never ending odyssee of problems i run into, especially when there might be groups which need to be added later.

In my head i am just wondering why the functionality to give multiple groups access to one item in the page tree has been removed in the first place.
Would love to hear some insight about this.

Thank you very much!

PS: I found this (german) old approach to user permissions which i really like, but which unfortunately can't be realized because of the change: https://punkt.de/de/blog/2017/typo3-backend-berechtigungen.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure, the TYPO3 core never had multiple users/groups owning a page. Where did you find this information?
What Christoph is describing is a way to organize usergroups, so you can granularly give a user specific permissions without much "hard coding" in his user settings. There's an extension adding a kind of multiple ownerships to pages: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/be_acl

Comment: Hi Julian,
take a look at the image located in the blog i posted in my question. There, it seems like it indeed was possible to assign multiple groups to one page. Also, a coworker, who worked with the rights system years ago told me about it...
I Think it would be a very good addition to the system, especially when having very complex solutions..

Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: That's what EXT:be_acl does ;) Have a look at its manual. The screens are a bit outdated (Looks like TYPO3 v4.x?), but shows exactly this multi-group-ownership of pages: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/be_acl/stable/Manual/Index.html#what-does-it-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

until now TYPO3 never had the option to give access to multiple groups in the basic right system.
Extensions might be able to enhance the data structure, but you can handle it on your own with the given possibilities of the core system:

First define roles for each right you want to grant. like:

- edit content
- edit news
- edit events
- edit products
- view news
- view events
- view products
  these groups are associated to the rights on the pages/ records.
  I would not define the roles so fine as in the article you mentioned. Normally I can define typoscript, DB-mounts, file-mounts, access-rights to one single group.

Then group them to the department roles:
If you have users which have access to multiple areas they can get a group which includes the basic groups. in this way you only need to assign one group to new users with the same rights

example:
department 1 -> edit content
department 2 -> edit products
department 3 -> edit news and events

as content may include links to news and products department 1 needs read access to news and products, which can be done with a DB-mount of the pages where these records are stored and and read access to these records (only configuration in the read-* groups.

in the access-rights the owner is irrelevant, the group should be the edit-group (with write/edit rights to records), others only can read. So everyone who can see the record folder can use the records for linking.

and we come to the groups for the departments:
*department_1* includes *edit_content*, *view_news*, *view_events*, *view_products*
*department_2* includes *edit_products*
*department_3* includes *edit_news*, *edit_events*, *view_products*

as news and events are handled parallel you might introduce groups to gather them
*edit_news_and_events* -> *edit_news*, *edit_events*
*read_news_and_events* -> *read_news*, *read_events*

and use these in this way:
*department_1* includes *edit_content*, *view_news_and_events*, *view_products*
*department_2* includes *edit_products*
*department_3* includes *edit_news_and_events*, *view_products*

But in this small example it is not neccessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's pretty similiar to the one i linked in my question, but helped me to get it over with and just create the specific roles. 26 user roles later and my issue is resolved. Still seems a little counter-intuitive.

Comment: It's not unusual to have hundreds of groups. It's important to have a clear, logical structure - but then you can manage nearly every requirement of permissions.